# Global on error handler in addon prevents the page from loading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, error-handling, firefox-addon, onerror

I have a Firefox addon which has a global `onerror` handler in the `content.js` script as shown below:

```
window.onerror = error => {
  console.log('On Error Handler');
  console.log(error);
}
```

This does not seem to be a problem in any other sites. But when I try to login to https://www.mint.com, it does not load the page after signing in. This happens only in Firefox, and only for this website (as far as I know). If I comment out the `onerror` handler, it works.

I see these two errors when the page does not load:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"

TypeError: window.ADRUM.events.VPageView is not a constructor
```

Has anyone faced this issue, or have any idea why the `onerror` handler is causing a problem?

Here is a simple Firefox addon I created to test the issue: [ff-addon-example](https://github.com/yedhukrishnan/ff-addon-example)